# Регулярное выражение C# подсчет

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка. 
В этой строке есть ключевое слово, допустим, "switch".
Так же есть "do". 
Мне необходимо узнать, сколько раз встречается "do" ПОСЛЕ "switch"
При этом интересует вхождение после первого switch. 
Как такое реализовать при помощи регулярного выражения?

Comment: А вы случайно не пытаетесь писать парсер на регулярках? Подумайте, что будет, если у вас попадётся ключевое слово с строковой константе или в комментарии.

Comment: Там анализатор кода, работающий не правильно. Исходников нет. Комментарии убираются.
Что работает не правильно:
Если после конструкции 
switch()
{
 case 
}

Встречаются конструкции 
do
{

}
while()

То одна переменная увеличивается на два. Мне же нужно на единицу.

Comment: Если у вас анализатор кода, то вам нужны не регулярки, а парсер. Комментарии убираются, а убирается ли строковые литералы?

Comment: Строковые литералы заменяются пустыми строками. В этом плане все нормально.

Comment: А литералы вида `$"lala {expression} lala"`? В `expression` может быть и `switch`. Вы всё пытаетесь решить проблему синтаксического разбора без парсера. Это заведомо проигрышный подход.

Comment: Пример: https://ideone.com/tDywha

Comment: Там анализатор Си. Потому лямбд там нет, но хватает других проблем. 
Я прекрасно понимаю, что чтобы написать нормальный анализатор нужно разбить код на лексемы, написать парсер и составить дерево синтаксиса. Но увы, на данном этапе моих знаний и времени, увы не хватит, потому и приходится писать костыли.

Comment: У вас Си? Охххх. С ним намного сложнее, т. к. препроцессор и макросы. У вас switch может прятаться в макросе, а макрос может быть переопределён в любом header'е. И да, за разбор кода на C требуйте повышения зарплаты: это _очень_ сложная тема.

Comment: Это учебное задание(2-й курс). Имхо, давать такие задания студентам - издевательство. Здесь 2 варианта: 1. Кривое решение 2. Какие-то сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Учебное задание? Ох. Ничего себе. Да, лучше поискать сторонние библиотеки, например, [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/csharp-target.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и без регулярок:

```
string s = "do do switchdo do od d o dododoodo do doswitch";
var parts = s.Split(new[] { "switch" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var doCount = parts.Skip(1).Sum(p => p.Split(new[] { "do" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(doCount);
```

Сплитим по `"switch"`, начинаем подсчет пропуская первую часть (она как раз до первого вхождения `"switch"`): для каждой части сплитим по `"do"` и вычитаем 1 из количества частей. Всё складываем.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но вряд ли такой вариант подойдет. В строке пробелов и табуляции нет :(

Comment: пробелы и табуляции на результат не влияют. Никак

Comment: Упс. Извиняюсь, да вы правы.